# Confusing syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

I keep getting the following error in my bash script when i attempt to run it, i can't seem to find the problem. I think it has something to do with how i am closing my loop(s). Any help would be much appreciated

```
bash: random: line 66: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
one=$RANDOM
two=$RANDOM

# Declare variable choice and assign value 4
choice=5
# Print to stdout
echo "1. -l"
echo "2. -m"
echo "3. -c"
echo "4. -i"
echo -n "Please choose a word [1,2,3,4]? "
while [ $choice -eq 5 ]; do


  #option -l
  if [ $choice -eq 1 ] ; then
   #do something

      else
      echo "Please make a choice between 1 -4 !"
      echo "1.-l"
      echo "2.-m"
      echo "3.-c"
      echo "4.-i"
      echo -n "Please choose a word [1,2,3 or 4]? "
      choice=5

      fi

echo"finished"
done
```

EDIT* Removed bulky code as it was causing an indent problem.

Comment: In addition to the answer by Marc. Proper use of indentation can save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Also, `echo"finished"` will try to find the command "echofinished" -- whitespace is critical in shells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't done a `done` for your while loop:

```
while [ $choice -eq 5 ]; do
   ...lots of stuff ...
done <---you're missing this
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am now getting line 62: syntax error near unexpected token `done' which is meant to be the done closing the if else loops. Any ideas?

Comment: @Paperghost You should probably (hard to tell with the indentation) put that `done` at the last line.

Comment: if-else statements are closed with `fi`. Please post further questions separately, rather than as comments to answers.